# SSH agent loses keys after logging out

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, key-authentication

I added my SSH key having typed

`ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

and `ssh-add -l` printed my key. But after logging out and logging in again I see

> The agent has no identities.

I've tried setting a very big lifetime period but it didn't help.

OS: Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS

Comment: Why do you want your identities survive a relogin?

Comment: I think you can add your SSH keys to the Gnome keyring, and that way you only have to enter your keyring password when you log in. It's a security vs usability compromise.

Comment: @Gilles, I didn't want to enter my passphrase every time I clone, pull or push. So I wanted something to store my passphrase. I'll try GNOME Keyring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu starts a new agent when you log in and kills it again when you log out.

Therefore the described behavior is perfectly fine.

Comment: Ubuntu starts a new agent when you log into Unity, not when you log in over ssh.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly are you calling logging out/in? If you quit the session in which the `ssh-agent` was running, then the `ssh-agent` you were talking to later was a different one than the one you loaded the keys into - the desktop session manager terminates all running user services (including ssh and gpg agents) at the end of a session.

You could hack around it by spawning your agent independently of any session and then injecting the correct environment variables into the session environment - you just need to find out from where does your display manager looks for user environment.